# How to use OnTouch, OnFocus and OnClick?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have some `TextViews` which I 1st want to change the Background color when they are clicked (focused) and 2nd a button press should apply a text change to the focused `TextView`.

I am just completely confused on what i need to do.

Here is how I change the background color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/purple_200" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/dark_gray" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Here is the xml part from my `TextViews`

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frame1_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/colorchange"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frame1_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/colorchange"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frame2_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/colorchange"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frame2_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/colorchange"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Here my java code:

```
private TextView currentTextView;

TextView Edit_frame1_1 = findViewById(R.id.frame1_1);
TextView Edit_frame1_2 = findViewById(R.id.frame1_2);
TextView Edit_frame2_1 = findViewById(R.id.frame2_1);
TextView Edit_frame2_2 = findViewById(R.id.frame2_2);

//noinspection AndroidLintClickableViewAccessibility
Edit_frame1_1.setOnTouchListener((view, event) -> {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        currentTextView = (TextView) view;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    });

//noinspection AndroidLintClickableViewAccessibility
Edit_frame1_2.setOnTouchListener((view, event) -> {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        currentTextView = (TextView) view;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

Edit_frame2_1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    currentTextView = (TextView) view;
});

Edit_frame2_2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    currentTextView = (TextView) view;
});
```

Now i have the first two TextViews partly working:
these are using a `OnTouchListener` but don't switch back to their orignal background (white) they just stay gray.

and the other two are partly working too. They will switch back to the white background, but i need to double click them to gain the focus for applying text trough my buttons.

I don't know how to make combined solution, to make it work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If the drawable is working as intended, then the only thing required would be to clear the focus of the previous TextView before focusing on another.

```
TextView currentTextView = null;

View.OnClickListener textViewClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(currentTextView == view)
            // It's the same TextView, so we don't need to do anything
            return;
        if(currentTextView != null) {
            // if currentTextView is not null, it contains the previously focused TextView
            // so clear it's focus here
        }
    
        // Here, request focus for the current TextView, using the `view` variable

        // and save it's reference to currentTextView variable
        currentTextView = (TextView) view;
    }
});

void yourMethod() {
    TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView1.setOnClickListener(textViewClickListener);

    // repeat for the rest of TextViews
}
```